# How to create Dynamic Regular Expression in javascript to validate decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate a decimal number based on the digits provided before the decimal and after the decimal.
Say i have a function which is having a regular expression and takes two parameters as digits before the decimal and digits after the decimal.

```
function validateDecimalNo(digitBeforeDec,digitAfterDec){
          //here i need to write the regular expression to validate the  decimal no based on the inputs.
            }
```

- If i pass 2,3 it should check decimal no as per this restriction
- If i pass 10,6 it should validate no as per this restriction
- If i pass 4,2 it should validate no as per this restriction

How to create the single dynamic regular expression to meet above requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you have literal syntax (`/regex/`, `{object}`, or even `"string"`), and you have the non-literal syntax (`new RegExp()`, `new Object()`, `new String()`).

With this provided, you can use the non-literal version of regex, which takes a string input:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp("hello", "i"); // -> /hello/i
```

So, this provided, we can make a function that creates a "dynamic regex" function (quotes because it's actually returning a new regex object every time it's run).

For instance:

```
var getRegex = function(startingSym, endingSym, optional){
  return new RegExp(startingSym + "(.+)" + endingSym, optional)
}
```

So, with this example function, we can use it like this:

```
var testing = getRegex("ab", "cd", "i");
console.log(testing);
// Output:
/ab(.+)cd/i
```

Comment: can u please provide a sample for above?It would be really useful as i am new bibe to reg expression

Comment: @user1991222, Yeah.  Give me second.

Comment: This is a fine explanation of how to create dynamic regexps, but it really should show how to do that in the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Why use regexp? Just check the number directly.

```
function make_decimal_validator(digitBeforeDec,digitAfterDec) {
    return function(no) {
        var parts = no.split('.');
        if (parts.length !== 2) throw "Invalid decimal number";
        return parts[0].length === digitBeforeDec && parts[1].length === digitAfterDec;
    };
}
```

Make your validator:

```
var validator23 = make_decimal_validator(2, 3);
validator23('12.345') // true
```